# Using a 'new' form to make database changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a user, who wants to be able to take vacation days off from work. My view looks like this:

```
<h2>Request Days Off</h2>

<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user, :url => vacation_days_path) do |f| %> 

  <div><%= f.label "How many vacation days would you like to take?" %>
  <%= f.number_field :vacation_days %></div>  

  <div><%= f.submit "Submit" %></div>

<% end %>
```

In my controller, I have new and create methods. In all examples of the 'create' method I see on the internet, there is a line of code similar to

```
 @person = User.new(user_params)   or whatever
```

My issue is that I don't have a vacation_days model. Only a controller. I want to edit the User database, but creating a new user cannot be the answer (right?).

How do I create a working create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really RESTful... However, if you want to update an existing user, you can do so like this

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

where `params[:id]` would hold the id of the user you want to update and `params[:user]` would hold the attributes you want to update.

Since you are using `form_for(@user)` with its form builder, it should be fine.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm wondering, what exactly isn't RESTful about this? How would I go about correcting it?

Comment: Pretty simple, if you want to update a User, you need to do that in a User controller (update method). You should not have to specify the `url` in your form, the default should be fine. Sometimes it's just not possible, I don't know your application and its goals and limitations :)

Comment: alright, between you and the other guy, it seems like I don't need a controller for vacation days. Guess I'll be scrapping a bunch of code.  Ah, the life of a junior developer. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome, this is how you'll learn :) Please consider accepting the answer if you think it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to me that you need your separate controller for vacation days. Simply have a vacation_days/edit view, which contains your form, and have it submit to users/update.

For clarity, your action should be editing and updating your user, rather than 'creating' one. So, your controller action to update your user should have the line:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Comment: Submitting to users/update sounds like right thing to do. Do I call that line of code in the form or what?